# error: bogus escape (end of line) when using re.findall with a wildcard

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to use re.findall to create a substring of a filepath that only gives me the part before the first backslash.
It's part of a for-loop with os.walk and I'm trying to get the first part of my root as the result of re.findall.

```
folder="Q:\\test\\test.gdb"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
   Quelle=re.findall('(.+?)\\',root)
```

This, however, produces error: bogus escape (end of line). From what I understand, this error is generated because I use the escape character at the end of the line. But, in my code example it is not at the end of the line? From my understanding I have to use it, to escape the  backslash so that my string includes everything of the path up until the first backslash. Is there any way around it?
When I use

```
folder="Q:\\test\\test.gdb"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
   Quelle=re.findall('(.+?):',root)
```

I correctly get the list of strings `['Q']`. But I want to include the `:` in my string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from `re`, not the interpreter.

Backslashes have meaning to regular expressions as escape characters too. For example, `r'\.'` is a literal period, not the class representing all characters, as `'.'` would be. A literal backslash therefore needs to be double escaped **again** at the regex level.

You have to paths going forward:

1. Double the backslash: `'(.+?)\\\\'`
2. Do the same thing, but use a raw string to make it look nicer: `r'(.+?)\\'`

Don't feel bad. There is even a special section in the official tutorial called ["The Backslash Plague"](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague) dealing with just this situation.

You can also search the list of special characters in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was helpful not only for solving my problem but also for helping me understand the problem and giving me more to read upon. Much appreciated!

Comment: @MalteJanßen. That's always the goal. Glad it worked out for you.